# Highlight duplicate including partial text matching in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

I have two sheets on a Google Sheet workbook as shown in the image. I need to highlight values from Column A of Sheet 1 when there is a match in Column A of Sheet 2. I use the conditional format rule `=countif(indirect("Sheet2!A1:A"),A1)` and things work fine.

But my requirement is also to show partial match in Sheet 1, e.g. if Sheet 1 has another row with "bikram sahu", it also should be highlighted. I tried wildcard characters(*), but that does not seem to work. I appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A1), LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:A"))))
```

[image: 0]